# Is there a way to print python datatable without waiting for user input at the end

Tags: python, py-datatable

I am printing a python datatable Frame. It pages when I do that, it's waiting for my input at the end, even for very small Frames. For example,

```
In [12]: DT = dt.Frame(A=range(5))

In [13]: DT
      A
---  --
 0    0
 1    1
 2    2
 3    3
 4    4

[5 rows x 1 column]
Press q to quit  ↑←↓→ to move  wasd to page  t to toggle types  g to jump
```

As you can see there is no need to navigate the Frame here. Is there a way to stop doing this for all python datatable Frames?

Thanks!

Comment: It would seem that you're not printing the frame here. does `print(DT)` give you the same prompt?

Comment: print(DT) simply shows the following:
`<Frame [5 rows x 1 col]>`

Comment: OK yes, but my point is that you're not actually *printing* the data frame. You're just querying the IDE by evaluating the statement: `DT` which is returning the `DT.__repr__`. You could use the `DT.to_dict` or `DT.to_list` methods (though this won't display a *tabular* view.

Comment: Worth noting, as of yesterday night, they've made some change so that `str(DT)` should result in a preview: http://github.com/h2oai/datatable/pull/1788

Answer (score 2):

As of 4/10/19, the latest version in github turns off the interactivity by default. Before 0.9.0 release we'd have to compile it from source to get it.

Answer (score 0):

In the current dev version, and in future datatable 0.9+ the display will be non-interactive by default. This behavior can be controlled via option `dt.options.display.interactive = True|False`.

In datatable 0.8 and younger, there are 2 ways to prevent the interactive prompt when displaying a Frame:

- either using `Frame.view(False)`:

  ```
  In [1]: import datatable as dt                                                                                                                                                       

  In [2]: DT = dt.Frame(A=range(5))                                                                                                                                                    

  In [3]: DT.view(False)
        A
  ---  --
   0    0
   1    1
   2    2
   3    3
   4    4

  [5 rows x 1 column]

  In [4]:
  ```
- or change the default behavior via

  ```
  In [4]: dt.Frame.view.__defaults__ = (False,)

  In [5]: DT 
        A
  ---  --
   0    0
   1    1
   2    2
   3    3
   4    4

  [5 rows x 1 column]
  ```